# Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server <xyz> using mongo-driver-core-4.1.2 jar

Tags: mongodb, multithreading, driver, monitor, socketstream

I have upgraded mongo java driver <mongodb.version>3.12.8</mongodb.version> to mongodb-driver-legacy  4.1.2. since then when ever i am trying to up the application in SIT getting below error .if i downgrade the version it works fine but with this version it throwing exception .

apart from mongo java driver , spring-data-mongodb is of 1.10.18 version and mongodb-driver-core is of 4.1.2 version.

This is my code to create mongoclient.

```
private MongoClientURI getClient(String uri, final boolean isCyberArkEnabled,
            final String cyberArkNickname, final String cyberArkAppID, final String cyberArkSafe,
            final String cyberArkObject, TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers, InputStream targetStream)
            throws Exception {
        MongoClientURI uriObj = null;
        final int maxConnections = 100;
        MongoClientOptions.Builder options;
        try {
            options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketTimeout(getMongoSocketTimeout())
                    // MongoSSLSocketFactory accepts self-signed certificate
                    .sslContext(createSSLContext(byPassTrustManagers, targetStream))
                    .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(false).connectionsPerHost(maxConnections);
            log.info("MongoURI before decoding:{}", uri);
            uri = decodeMongoPassword(uri, isCyberArkEnabled, cyberArkNickname, cyberArkAppID, cyberArkSafe,
                    cyberArkObject);
            log.info("MongoURI after decoding:{}", uri);
            uriObj = new MongoClientURI(uri, options);
        } catch (MongoException ex) {
            log.error("Exception while instantiating mongo client");
        }

        return uriObj;
    }

    private SSLContext createSSLContext (TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers, InputStream targetStream)
                throws Exception {
            final String protocol = CoreModule.getConfiguration().getString("TLSv1.2");
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);
            sslContext.init(null, byPassTrustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            targetStream.close();
            return sslContext;}
    


     
        Error - 
        
            2022-05-13 10:01:30 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='627e64bac2dd3e1960e5ca66', description='null'}-maas-gtz-p05-m0005.nam.nsroot.net:37017] [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server maas-gtz-p05-m0005.nam.nsroot.net:37017 
            com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
                at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:648) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at 
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:513) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:356) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:280) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```